# trying to add multiple similar objects to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to write a function that adds a new "row" that has an optional "cell" to an object. Here is my code:

```
   var init = function() {
    var num = 0;
    var count = 0;

    var SC = {}

    var rowAdd = function() {
        num = num + 1
        var cellstate = false;

        var objCount = count + 1

        var rowObj = {
            number: num,
            cell: cellstate
        }

        return SC.rowObj;
    }

    var initialize = function() {
        rowAdd();
    }
initialize();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();

    addRowBtn.click(function() {
        rowAdd();
    });

    addCellBtn.click(function() {
        SC.row1.cell = true;
    });
});
```

This approach rewrites the row everytime i call `rowAdd()`. In the end I want a single object `SC` to contain every row, and each row should have a `cell` property. How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you even calling `rowAdd()`?

Comment: Have you tried using array...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can just use `num` for `objCount` too and no need for `cellState` variable.

```
var init = function() {
    var num = 0, SC = {}

    var rowAdd = function() {
        num = num + 1;
        SC["row" + num] = {
            number: num,
            cell: false
        }
        return SC;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli--is it possible to access an object with string key like this?

Comment: Yes you can set as well get the object value with string key.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli--even if the key is a concatenation?

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate and build a string. But the key should be a valid key should not contain any special characters.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli--thanks for the help. do you think you could help me with another problem? Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167318/trying-to-remove-and-store-and-object-with-detach

Comment: Just answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

How about making `SC` an array and pushing the new row onto the array:

```
var SC = [];

var rowAdd = function() {
    num = num + 1
    var cellstate = false;

    var objCount = count + 1;
    var rowObj = "row" + objCount;

    var rowObj = {
        number: num,
        cell: cellstate
    }

    return SC.push(rowObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have an array object on `SC` to hold your rows.

```
var SC = { rows: [] };
```

And then add to it

```
SC.rows.push(rowObj);
```

To access

```
SC.rows[index]
```