# trying to remove and store and object with detach()

Tags: javascript, jquery, detach

I am trying to remove an object and store it (in case a user wants to retrieve it later). I have tried storing the object in a variable like it says in the thread below:

[How to I undo .detach()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764254/how-to-i-undo-detach)

But the `detach()` does not remove the element from the DOM or store it. I am also not getting any error messages. Here is the code I am using to detach the element:

```
function MMtoggle(IDnum) {
        var rowID = "row" + IDnum;
        var jRow = '#' + rowID;
        thisMMbtn = $(jRow).find(".addMMbtn");
        var light = false;
        var that = this;
        if (light == false) {
            thisMMbtn.bind("click",
                function() {
                    var thisRow = $(this).closest(".txtContentRow");
                    var thisTxt = thisRow.find(".txtContent");
                    var cellStr = '<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>';
                    $(cellStr).appendTo(thisTxt);
                    $(this).unbind("click");
                    light = true;
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            thisMMbtn.bind("click",
                function() {
                    var thisRow = $(this).closest(".txtContentRow");
                    thisMM = thisRow.find(".mmCell");
                    SC[rowID].rcbin = thisMM.detach(); //here is where I detach the div and store it in an object
                    $(this).unbind("click");
                    light = false;
                }
            );
        }
    }

    MMtoggle(g.num);
```

A fiddle of the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pScJc/

(the button that detaches is the '+' button on the right. It is supposed to add a div and then detach it when clicked again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I don't think so you need `detach` for what you are trying to achieve.

Instead try this code.

```
    thisMMbtn.bind("click",
        function() {
            var thisRow = $(this).closest(".txtContentRow");
            var thisTxt = thisRow.find(".txtContent");
            var $mmCell = thisTxt.find('.mmCell');
            if($mmCell.length == 0){
                $mmCell = $('<div class = "mmCell prep"></div>')
                          .appendTo(thisTxt).hide();
            }
            $mmCell.toggle();
            //$(this).unbind("click");
        }
    );
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/pScJc/2/)**

Comment: @ShankarSangoli--interesting... but just out of curiosity, did i use `detach()` incorrectly?

Comment: Your `detach` code was not getting executed because you were unbinding the `click` handler.